# The lack of non-capturing Task.Yield forces me to use Task.Run, why follow that?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Apologies in advance if this question is opinion-based. The lack of [Task.Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield.aspx) version which wouldn't capture the execution context was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742522/taskex-yieldtaskscheduler). **Apparently, this feature was present in some form in early versions of Async CTP but was removed because it could easily be misused**.

IMO, such feature could be as easily misused as `Task.Run` itself. Here's what I mean. Imagine there's an awaitable `SwitchContext.Yield` API which schedules the continuation on ThreadPool, so the execution will always continues on a thread different from the calling thread. I could have used it in the following code, which starts some CPU-bound work from a UI thread. I would consider it a convenient way of continuing the CPU-bound work on a pool thread:

```
class Worker
{
    static void Log(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, String.Format(format, args));
    }

    public async Task UIAction()
    {
        // UI Thread
        Log("UIAction");

        // start the CPU-bound work
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
        var workTask = DoWorkAsync(cts.Token); 

        // possibly await for some IO-bound work 
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Log("after Task.Delay");

        // finally, get the result of the CPU-bound work
        int c = await workTask;
        Log("Result: {0}", c);
    }

    async Task<int> DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // start on the UI thread
        Log("DoWorkAsync");

        // switch to a pool thread and yield back to the UI thread
        await SwitchContext.Yield();
        Log("after SwitchContext.Yield");
        // continue on a pool thread

        int c = 0;
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // do some CPU-bound work on a pool thread: counting cycles :)
            c++;
            // and use async/await too
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }

        return c;
    }

}
```

Now, without `SwitchContext.Yield`, `DoWorkAsync` would look like below. It adds some extra level of complexity in form of async delegate and task nesting:

```
async Task<int> DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // start on the UI thread
    Log("DoWorkAsync");

    // Have to use async delegate
    // Task.Run uwraps the inner Task<int> task
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // continue on a pool thread
        Log("after Task.Yield");

        int c = 0;
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // do some CPU-bound work on a pool thread: counting cycles :)
            c++;
            // and use async/await too
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }

        return c;
    });
}
```

That said, implementing `SwitchContext.Yield` may actually be quite simple and (I dare to say) efficient:

```
public static class SwitchContext
{
    public static Awaiter Yield() { return new Awaiter(); }

    public struct Awaiter : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
    {
        public Awaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return false; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => ((Action)state)(), continuation);
        }

        public void GetResult() { }
    }
}
```

So, **my question is**, why should I prefer the second version of `DoWorkAsync` over the first one, and why would using `SwitchContext.Yield` be considered a bad practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was "SwitchTo" removed from Async CTP / Release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363413/why-was-switchto-removed-from-async-ctp-release)

Comment: I indeed prefer the 2nd version (with Task.Run) because I hate non-local effects. Switching threads is non-local because it affects all following code. Imagine this being split across methods and classes. Hard to review.

Comment: @usr, do you mean avoiding this for code running on specific `SynchronizationContext`? Otherwise, it would apply to any method calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`, while ConfigureAwait is indeed a good thing to do if you don't care about continuation context. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Noseratio this is a valid concern regarding `ConfigureAwait`. But `ConfigureAwait` effects are usually constrained to the containing async method. That makes the effect mostly-local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *have* to put the `Task.Run` in `DoWorkAsync`. Consider this option:

```
public async Task UIAction()
{
    // UI Thread
    Log("UIAction");

    // start the CPU-bound work
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
    var workTask = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(cts.Token)); 

    // possibly await for some IO-bound work 
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Log("after Task.Delay");

    // finally, get the result of the CPU-bound work
    int c = await workTask;
    Log("Result: {0}", c);
}
```

This results in code with much clearer intent. `DoWorkAsync` is a [naturally synchronous method, so it has a synchronous signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). `DoWorkAsync` neither knows nor cares about the UI. The `UIAction`, which does care about the UI thread, pushes off the work onto a background thread using `Task.Run`.

As a general rule, try to "push" any `Task.Run` calls up out of your library methods as much as possible.

Comment: That's a good point, however, my `DoWorkAsyc` has an `await` inside it. It's a mix, but that's not so rare. Thus, I'd still have to call it like `var workTask = Task.Run(async () => await DoWorkAsync(cts.Token))` in your version, right?

Comment: Actually, mixing `async` and CPU-intensive code in the same method *is* rare. But in that case you can leave `DoWorkAsync` with an `async` signature and still call it the same way in my answer.

Comment: In my particular case the CPU-intensive code is a background spellchecker. It uses `async/await` to suspend/resume its work depending on user typing activity (using a task akin event sync. primitive) and to call the spelling server if the word is not in a local cache.