# Why am I still on the Main Thread when I specified ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am trying to understand how async/await keywords works. I have a textblock on a WPF window bind to a TextBlockContent string property and a button which trigger on click ChangeText().

Here is my code :

```
public async void ChangeText()
{
     string mystring = await TestAsync();
     this.TextBlockContent= mystring;
}

private async Task<string> TestAsync()
{
     var mystring = await GetSomeString().ConfigureAwait(false);
     mystring = mystring + "defg";
     return mystring;
}

private Task<string> GetSomeString()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return "abc";
    });
}
```

From my readings, I understood that ConfigureAwait set to false would allow me to specify that I do not want to save the Current context for the "rest" of the Task that needs to be executed after the await keyword.

After debugging i realize that when i have this code, sometime the code is running on the Main thread after the line : *await GetSomeString().ConfigureAwait(false);* while i specifically added the configure await.

I would have expected it to always run on a different thread that the one it was in before it entered the Task.

Can someone help me understand why?

Thank you very much

Comment: My 2 cents: if you really want to make sure you continue on a new thread after `await`, you can with a [custom awaiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779393/the-lack-of-non-capturing-task-yield-forces-me-to-use-task-run-why-follow-that). This is considered a bad practice, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It could well be that the task you're running is completing immediately - which means that the `await` doesn't even need to schedule a continuation. An `async` method only schedules a continuation when it needs to; if you await something which has already completed, it just keeps going - in the same thread.

`ConfigureAwait` is a hint that you don't *need* to continue in the same context; it's not a requirement that you *mustn't* continue on the same context.

If you change your task to something that doesn't complete immediately - e.g. call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` (which of course you wouldn't normally do) I'd expect you to see a change in behaviour.

It's possible that I've missed something else and that this *isn't* the cause of the problem, but it would at least be worth trying that first.

Comment: Well it seems to be that. I knew that the scheduler wouldn't schedule a task if already completed like Task.FromResult(...) but i didn't know that if the execution is almost "instant" it would consider it directly completed. Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @Alexei: No, I mean Thread.Sleep. The point is to create a task which doesn't complete quickly. Sleeping is an easy way of doing that.

Comment: Right... OP starts new task. My comment would make sense if it would be part of the `async` method, not `Task.Run`.