# Task continuation with own ThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Is it possible to force the continuation of an async-await statement to run on a thread of a custom ThreadPool?

Context: I'm running an ASP-Application and doing quite a bit of work in the background. I'm doing all the work via a self written ThreadPool, but if I use the async-await Pattern, the continuation always runs on a thread named "Worker Thread".
I'm pretty sure that's a thread from the default ThreadPool which is also used to process HTTP requests.
This leads to a starvation of these requests as all the threads of the default ThreadPool are busy continuing my background work.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the weel why don't you raise the ThreadPool's limits? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That does not sound right. You are hitting thread-pool limits? Then you probably have far too much concurrent blocking work.; Consider, just increasing the thread-pool limits.

Comment: Increasing the thread pool limits doesn't solve my problem. I'm doing a lot of IO using completion ports so the blocking is not on the thread level. But since the project is doing massive parallel work (6000 parallel tasks or more) I want to run them completely separate from the framework thread pool.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a web server needs to handle more clients than it can possibly handle?  It happened.

Comment: @Hans We're talking about one single client. The problem is that all the threads the system uses to handle requests are busy waiting on my long running tasks. I want to move that to my own threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can create a custom [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) that works with your custom `ThreadPool` and set it before running the async operation.

```
var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current; 
try 
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext()); 
    
    // async operations.
} 
finally 
{  
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx); 
}
```

More on how to create a custom `SynchronizationContext`: [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)

---

Although a custom ThreadPool is rarely necessary. You should probably try and optimize while using the built-in one instead.

Comment: @MartinWalter, I'd warn you against installing a custom synchronization context in ASP.NET, even for the scope of single `await`. Not only you'll loose the `HttpContext.Current` and other ambient HTTP request properties, but you *may* also  confuse some ASP.NET runtime APIs which rely upon `AspNetSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for the advice, but I don't have those problems: My work is completely independent of a HttpContext (it doesn't even know it's running inside an ASP project), and I'm changing the synchronization context only for my own threads.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need a custom thread pool, especially if you're doing a lot parallel I/O which naturally uses IOCP threads. This applies to any other API which only acquires a thread from the pool when its task has completed (e.g, `Task.Delay`).

Usually you do `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` for continuation to happen on the same thread the `task` has completed on:

```
// non-IOCP (worker) continuation thread 
await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false); 
// IOCP continuation thread
await stream.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now, in ASP.NET you don't even need to use `ConfigureAwait`. ASP.NET's `AspNetSynchronizationContext` doesn't maintain thread affinity for `await` continuations, *unlike* `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` or `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` do for a UI app. Your continuations will run on whatever thread the task has completed on, as is. `AspNetSynchronizationContext` just "enters" the ASP.NET context on that thread, to make sure your code has access to `HttpContext` and other relevant ASP.NET request ambient state information.

You can increase the default number of IOCP and worker threads with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` to account for [`ThreadPool` stuttering problems](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/08/clr-thread-pool-injection-stuttering-problems/).

If your only reason for custom thread pool is to limit the level of parallelism for your tasks, use TPL Dataflow or simply `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` (check ["Throttling asynchronous tasks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks)).

That said, you can have a very precise control over the `Task` continuation if you implement a custom awaiter. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18779393/1768303) for a basic example of that.